# How to save contacts in the .VCF format

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a class to hold data and a list of that class.
Here is my code.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<GoogleContacts> contacts = new List<GoogleContacts>();
        contacts.Add(new GoogleContacts { title = "A", email = "B", im = "X" });
        contacts.Add(new GoogleContacts { title = "C", email = "D", im = "Y" });
        contacts.Add(new GoogleContacts { title = "E", email = "F", im = "Z" });
    }
}


public class GoogleContacts
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string im { get; set; }
}
```

I want to save those data in a .VCF file in local Disk.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just create a StringBuilder instance and write the contents of the .VCF to it.

```
var contact = new GoogleContacts() { ... };

var vcf = new StringBuilder();
vcf.Append("TITLE:" + contact.Title + System.Environment.NewLine); 
//...
```

Afterwards you can save it to a file using the static [WriteAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealltext.aspx)(...) method of the File type.

```
var filename = @"C:\mycontact.vcf";
File.WriteAllText(filename, vcf.ToString());
```

Just open a .vcf file with a text editor to explore its contents. Since you only require a couple of properties it should be easy to figure out.

A small example:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
FN:Mr. John Smith
TITLE:Developer
ORG:Microsoft
BDAY:1979-12-10
VERSION:2.1
END:VCARD
```

If you want to include an image you have to base 64 encode it.

Comment: Refer this link for more clarification.   [link]  (http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/creating-vcard-with-image-in-net)