# How to share contact data of my app with whtsapp in .vcf /vcard format using xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I have an application that creates a .vcf file after you input data. it stores storage provided by the phone, I want to click on a list view item and get the vcf file and share it via Email, SMS, WhatsApp, Skype etc how do I implement this in IOS and Android.

Thank you

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but you want to share your application's .vcf  via different apps?

Comment: No. I have stored my contact name and number in mobile local storage using Sqlite database. But now i want to share that contact with whatsapp, email,message.. etc. but in Vcard format.

Comment: @Prachi looks like you want to share the .vcf file. I have already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52151409/file-download-in-xamarin-forms/52172875#52172875

Comment: @NirmalSubedi yes i want share .vcf file in whatsapp. But which Share plugin i have to use for share .vcf file. How would i generate my string data into .vcf.

Comment: Is this you want? [how-to-save-contacts-in-the-vcf-format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446295/how-to-save-contacts-in-the-vcf-format)

Comment: @jack Hua yes, i want that how would i make my string for .vcf(VCARD)  with image. Here I have attached one example which i have implement:

Comment: var vcf = new StringBuilder();
            vcf.AppendLine("BEGIN:VCARD");
            vcf.AppendLine("VERSION:3.0");
            vcf.AppendLine($"N:{per.FirstName}; {per.LastName}; ;;");
            vcf.AppendLine($"FN:{per.LastName} {per.FirstName}");
            vcf.AppendLine($"ORG:{per.Organization}");
            vcf.AppendLine($"TITLE:{per.Organization}");
            vcf.AppendLine($"PHOTO;ENCODING=b;TYPE=PNG:{data}");
            vcf.AppendLine($"TEL;TYPE=work,voice;VALUE=uri:tel:{per.PhoneNumber}");
           
            vcf.AppendLine("END:VCARD");

Comment: but my photo was not added . Please correct me if i was wrong.

Comment: @PrachiGandhi  To add a image, you can use 

`builder.AppendLine("PHOTO;ENCODING=BASE64;TYPE=JPEG:");

builder.AppendLine(Convert.ToBase64String(Image));

builder.AppendLine(string.Empty);` Add this code right before vCard line where VCARD:END is appended to builder. Note that after image we have to output two line breaks. Without them image is not shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the answer of creating .vcf file which is given below. and for share that file follow this link : https://github.com/adamped/ShareDialog

private void Share_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var _btn = sender as Button;
                var record = _btn.BindingContext as Contact;
                int tempcontactID = record.ContactID;

```
            if (record.CardFrontImage == null)
            {
                record.CardImage = record.CardBackImage;
            }
            else
            {
                record.CardImage = record.CardFrontImage;
            }

            string baseimage = Convert.ToBase64String(record.CardImage);

            var vcf = new StringBuilder();  //vcf code start
            vcf.AppendLine("BEGIN:VCARD");
            vcf.AppendLine("VERSION:3.0");
            vcf.AppendLine($"N:{record.ContactName};{string.Empty}; ;;");
            vcf.AppendLine($"FN:{record.ContactName}");
            vcf.AppendLine($"ORG:{record.CompanyName}");
            vcf.AppendLine($"TITLE:{record.Designation}");
            vcf.AppendLine($"PHOTO;ENCODING=BASE64;TYPE=PNG:{baseimage}");
            vcf.AppendLine($"TEL;TYPE=work,voice;VALUE=uri:tel:{record.PhoneNumber}");

            vcf.AppendLine("END:VCARD");

            string fileName = Path.Combine("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.Gamma.GammaNetworkingApp/files/", record.ContactID + record.ContactName + ".vcf");

            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(fileName))
            {
                writer.Write(vcf.ToString());
            }

            string text = File.ReadAllText(fileName);

            bool doesExist = File.Exists(fileName);

            if (doesExist == true)
            {
                var share = DependencyService.Get<IShare>();
                share.Show("Contact share", record.ContactName, fileName);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string test = ex.ToString();
            Navigation.PushAsync(new HomePage());
        }
    }
```